# Why is Nested while loop not working in 2nd try c++?

Tags: c++, loops, input, while-loop

This is guessing game
So what I am trying to do is ask user after every game completion whether they wanna play again. `2nd last line of code` the program run but  `while(guessedNumber != secretNumber && guessCounter != 0 )` does not get executed 2nd time

What should I do ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
//int secretNumber;
int main()
{
//    srand(time(NULL));
//    int secretNumber = rand() % 14;    //declaring variables for STORED NUMBERS
    int guessedNumber;       //it is number guessed by user
    int guessCounter = 3;    //number of times user have guesses left
    char wannaPlayAgain = 'y';

    while(wannaPlayAgain != 'n'){
        srand(time(NULL));
        int secretNumber = rand() % 14;
        while(guessedNumber != secretNumber && guessCounter != 0 ){  //it is telling that until 'guessedNumber' is not equal to 'guessCounter' and 'guessCounter' is not 0 you should run loop
            cout << "guess the number: ";                           //asks user input
            cin >> guessedNumber;
            guessCounter--;
//          cout << "you have " << guessCounter << " guesses left \n";
            if(guessedNumber == secretNumber){
                cout << "\n\n         YOU WIN\n\n";
            }else if(guessCounter == 0){
//            guessCounter--;
                cout << "you have " << guessCounter << " guesses left \n";
            }else if(guessedNumber <= secretNumber){
                cout << "Too low \n";
 //             guessCounter--;
                cout << "you have " << guessCounter << " guesses left \n";
            }else if(guessedNumber >= secretNumber){
                cout << "Too high \n";
 //           guessCounter--;
                cout << "you have " << guessCounter << " guesses left \n";
            }
        }
        if(guessCounter == 0){       //and when loop exits it prints 'YOU LOSE' if 'guessCounter' is 0
            cout << "\n\n         YOU LOSE\n\n" << endl;
            cout<< "Secret number was "<< secretNumber << endl;
        }
        cout<< "Do you wanna play again[y/n]: ";
        cin>> wannaPlayAgain;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @idclev463035818 how do I reset the value

Comment: @idclev463035818 Umm i got it i need to Initialize the ```guessCounter``` after first while loop

Comment: Only call `srand` *once*.

Comment: I don't get if i call srand only once how will the value of```secretNumber``` change for next game please elaborate little more @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: `srand` is to seed the pseudo random number generator. A common misunderstanding ist that prng are not really producing randomness. If you use the same seed you will get the same "random" numbers (and that is actually an important property of prngs). `srand` might use the same seed when called too fast and then the number will be the same

Comment: The random number generator don't reset when your loop iterates. The next time you call `rand` you will get a new random number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relevant parts of your code are:

```
int guessCounter = 3;    //number of times user have guesses left
char wannaPlayAgain = 'y';

while(wannaPlayAgain != 'n'){
    while(...blablabla.. && guessCounter != 0 ){
        guessCounter--;
    }
    if(guessCounter == 0){
        cout << "\n\n         YOU LOSE\n\n" << endl;
        cout<< "Secret number was "<< secretNumber << endl;
    }
    cout<< "Do you wanna play again[y/n]: ";
    cin>> wannaPlayAgain;
}
return 0;
```

You decrement `guessCounter`, when it reaches `0` the player looses, can choose to play again, but you never reset `guessCounter`. The next turn starts with `0`.

This is one of the problems that you would not have encountered if you just declare variables in the most narrow scope possible:

```
char wannaPlayAgain = 'y';

while(wannaPlayAgain != 'n'){
    // vv ------------------------  MOVE IT HERE
    int guessCounter = 3;    //number of times user have guesses left
    // ^^ --------------------------

    while(...blablabla.. && guessCounter != 0 ){
        guessCounter--;
    }
    if(guessCounter == 0){
        cout << "\n\n         YOU LOSE\n\n" << endl;
        cout<< "Secret number was "<< secretNumber << endl;
    }
    cout<< "Do you wanna play again[y/n]: ";
    cin>> wannaPlayAgain;
}
return 0;
```

You only need `guessCounter` inside the game loop. There is no need to make it global for all games. Declaring it only when you need it eliminates your bug.

The same goes for `guessedNumber`. There is no problem with it in your code now, but declaring it only when you need it eliminates potential mistakes.

Also note that you should seed the random number generator only once, not inside the loop. The resolution can be only 1 second and a lucky and fast player might see the exact same number on consecutive games.